# How to print cell value as many times as its neighboring cell value (unpivoting)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have some data that is pivoted or summarized that I would need to "unpivot". The data looks like this:

```
1000000 6
1245142 4
1245246 6
```

I would need it to look like this (each value in first column is printed as many times as the value in second column dictates):

```
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1000000
1245142
1245142
1245142
1245142
1245246
1245246
1245246
1245246
1245246
1245246
```

etc.

Any simple way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Hi Markus, can you let us know what you've attempted so far? Also, you may well need to use VBA for this so it would be useful to know how much you know about VBA

Answer (score 1):

Some VBA like this, just adjust as needed.

It looks in the defined range for numbers, checks next to them for positive integers and then prints them in another column based on the adjacent cell.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Integer
d = 1

For Each c In Range("A1:A3")
i = c.Offset(, 1).Value

  If i > 0 Then

    For x = 1 To i
    Cells(d, 4) = c.Value
    d = d + 1
    Next x

  End If

Next c

End Sub
```